# Isabelle: locale interpration about record fails in proof

Tags: locale, record, isabelle, interpretation

Using the Algebra library, I encountered the following problem. In a proof I wanted to interpret the additive structure of a ring as a group. Here is a sample code:

```
theory aaa
imports "~~/src/HOL/Algebra/Ring"
begin

lemma assumes "ring R"
shows "True"
proof-
interpret ring R by fact
interpret additive: comm_group "⦇carrier = carrier R, mult = add R, one = zero R⦈" by(unfold_locales)
```

But I can't access the facts from the group locale. Typing

```
thm additive.m_assoc
```

gives the message "Undefined fact". However, it works when I define the additive structure with the monoid.make command:

```
interpret additivee: comm_group "monoid.make (carrier R) (add R) (zero R)" sorry

thm additivee.m_assoc
```

It also works if I try to do the same for the multiplicative structure, or if I remove

```
interpret ring R by fact
```

Any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands `interpretation` and `interpret` only register those facts from locales that are not already in scope from previous interpretations. The `ring` locale is a sub-locale of `comm_group` with the prefix `add` and precisely the parameter instantiation you are giving in the first interpretation. Since all these facts are already available (albeit under a different name), `interpret` does not add them once more. In the interpretation `additivee`, the instantiation of the parameters is different, so the facts from the locale are added.